# nifi 1.21.1 all menu icons are grayed out due to policy. Work around is to manually add user to all policies

Tags: ldap, apache-nifi, policy, disable

I installed nifi 1.21.0 and enabled ldap authentication.
When I log in nifi web gui, on nifi canvas, somehow all icons are grayed out

I could make it all work by manually add users to allow write to all policies.
I'm wondering if there's a way to automatically done without the manual efforts.
Or it has to be something done manually when I add a user.

I also noticed that even if I put the user in admin group, and admin (I'm not sure if it's a hidden user or the group) can write all policies. This new user still gets all icons disabled.

Comment: I wanted to add a screen shot to the body of the post but got forbidden error some how. My  screen shot file is only 120k, well under the file size limit.

Answer (score 0):

I have an anthorizations.xml file which include a root processor group id (blank canvas) from another nifi instance. Right click on blank canvas and select manage policies to check if you have access to root processor group id.

Root processor group id can be found on the Operate floating dialogue window.
Add it to authorizations.xml with full permission login identify:

```
<!--Just modify eef6e73f-e170-4469-ae66-7d42d5a3550c to the root NiFi Flow-->
<policy identifier="403ab01f-0184-1000-b6ad-e9616cb80efb" resource="/operation/process-groups/eef6e73f-e170-4469-ae66-7d42d5a3550c" action="W">
    <group identifier="fd59cb8d-0180-1000-3c6b-df11071587a0"/>
    <group identifier="6529d0b7-0178-1000-9493-9e9789277501"/>
</policy>
<!--Just modify eef6e73f-e170-4469-ae66-7d42d5a3550c to the root NiFi Flow-->
<policy identifier="403ad413-0184-1000-7346-db46e554a005" resource="/provenance-data/process-groups/eef6e73f-e170-4469-ae66-7d42d5a3550c" action="R">
    <group identifier="fd59cb8d-0180-1000-3c6b-df11071587a0"/>
    <group identifier="652a31a8-0178-1000-f834-af2170415867"/>
    <group identifier="6529d0b7-0178-1000-9493-9e9789277501"/>
</policy>
<!--Just modify eef6e73f-e170-4469-ae66-7d42d5a3550c to the root NiFi Flow-->
<policy identifier="403b3ab2-0184-1000-7b2a-9b9397e8ff15" resource="/policies/process-groups/eef6e73f-e170-4469-ae66-7d42d5a3550c" action="R">
    <group identifier="6529d0b7-0178-1000-9493-9e9789277501"/>
</policy>
<!--Just modify eef6e73f-e170-4469-ae66-7d42d5a3550c to the root NiFi Flow-->
<policy identifier="403b5dc6-0184-1000-8fb6-4723ee3d5df7" resource="/policies/process-groups/eef6e73f-e170-4469-ae66-7d42d5a3550c" action="W">
    <group identifier="6529d0b7-0178-1000-9493-9e9789277501"/>
</policy>
```